# Unable to mount external hard drive, any information is very slow

Tags: hard-drive, mount, ntfs

I have used a My Passport 2Tera for 2 years and it suddenly it runs very slow (around 10 minutes until windows mount it and 1-2 minutes to list a folder content). I've seen some similar issues and tried to run `ntfsfix` here is what I get:

```
Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x44524352  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 8: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x44524352)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x44524352  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 8: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x44524352)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Checking for self-located MFT segment... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x44524352  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 8: Invalid argument
OK
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x44524352  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 8: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x44524352)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Since that, Windows or ubuntu stops mounting it so I can't run `chkdsk` (as i know).
I tried `testdisk`, I can access to my data with it, but like on Windows it's very long to list a directory content, I try to copy my data but of course it's extremely slow. I also write partition structure with testdisk but it doesn't change anything.
I'm thinking to dump the partition, but I'm not sure it will solve my problem so I don't want to lose all my data for nothing...

I know that they are a lot of help but I tried a lot of things, but none of them seem to solve my problem.

If it could help, here is the `mount` output:

```
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x44524352  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 8: Argument invalide
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x44524352)
Failed to load $MFT: Erreur d'entrée/sortie
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc': Erreur d'entrée/sortie
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Did you have any idea ?